# Convert shapes and lines into a single outline

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Coming back to Illustrator after many years away, and I seem to have forgotten how to do what seems really elementary. Forgive my quick hand sketches... I drew some circles (blue) and lines (black):

[image: enter code here]

I want to convert everything into a single path out of which I can delete specific segments, and end up with this final shape:

[image]

What obvious method am I missing, O great hive mind?

Answer (score 6):

Although pathfinder will definitely work, using the *Shapebuilder Tool* (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>) will probably be much simpler.

Just *Select All* and *Click+Drag* over areas to merge. Then select the area to delete and remove it (see included GIF)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it is using **Pathfinder**.

Given your example I would:

- Your example [img 1]
- Close all the lines into a single shape [img 2]
- Use pathfinder to unite the resulted shape with the two farther
  circles [img 3]
- Use pathfinder with minus front to cut the middle circle out of the
  newly created shape [img 4]

[image]

Comment: It may be simpler to use pathfinder

Comment: I guess I'm a lot more remedial than I thought. Just spent half an hour and can't figure out how to accomplish your step #2 "Close all the lines into a single shape".  :-(

Comment: @BrianDunning You can either manually draw the connecting 3 lines from endpoint to endpoint, select all the lines, right click and select join or you can join them using the Pen tool.